# Is it possible to connect multiple output screens to single machine

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, cpu, c#

Suppose i have four screens A,B,C,D connected to single machine. I need to play different video to each screen which control and coordinated by application running on single machine.

Problems i am facing

1. How to connect four screens to cpu.
2. How to identify individual machine at run time.
3. How to send video output to each machine.

For this i am using windows form with c#. Please specify all hardware needs also.

Comment: This is very possible. Most high end video cards support up to 3 monitors, so you'll need about 2 video cards. On top of that, you'll need to make sure your motherboard supports two video cards. Its not difficult, just a little pricey. Your video card driver will be able to identify all of your monitors. Finally, depending on what screen you send your programs to, those are the screens that will show the output

Comment: @Sal i need little more help from you can you please tell me hardware i need on mother board and video card side.

Comment: @chetan, shopping recommendations are off topic here.  He did tell you you need at least two video cards (cards should be able to drive 2 monitors each) and a motherboard that can fit the two cards you select.  Beyond that this question is off-topic.

Comment: @heavyd okay sorry for that.